# ionic 3.4.0 keyboard import

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, keyboard, ionic2

My Ionic info:

global packages:

```
@ionic/cli-utils : 1.4.0
Cordova CLI      : 6.5.0 
Ionic CLI        : 3.4.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts              : 1.3.6
@ionic/cli-plugin-cordova       : 1.4.0
@ionic/cli-plugin-ionic-angular : 1.3.1
Cordova Platforms               : android 6.1.2 ios 4.3.1
Ionic Framework                 : ionic-angular 3.1.1
```

System:

```
Node       : v8.0.0
OS         : Linux 4.8
Xcode      : not installed
ios-deploy : not installed
ios-sim    : not installed
npm        : 3.10.10
```

I use:

```
import { Keyboard } from '@ionic-native/keyboard';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-search-modal',
  templateUrl: 'search-modal.html',
  providers: [ Keyboard ]
})

constructor(public keyboard: Keyboard) {}
```

I have a method that runs `this.keyboard.show ();` When you open a view and give focus to an input.

But when I run `npm run ionic: serve`
I get this error:

```
Roller, public tabsService: TabsService, public keyboard: Keyboard, private renderer: Renderer, private elem
(node:2349) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): Error: watcher error: /home/my-folder/my-app/home/my-folder/my-app/src/**/*.(ts|html|s(c|a)ss): Error: watch /home/my-folder/my-app/src ENOSPC
(node:2349) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
[11:31:09]  copy finished in 2.79 s
```

*Sorry for the translation, I speak Spanish*

Comment: Why are you running that command ? "npm run ionic: serve" instead of "ionic serve"

Comment: ENOSPC - means there is no space on the drive

Comment: @Alberick0

Because the "ionic serve" was not working since I updated.

Comment: @FaberHozzHerreraMartinez you should be serving with ionic serve, Did you check if your drive is full as misha130, suggested above ?

Comment: @Alberick0 misha130
I decided not to use the keyboard event, and just point the focus to the input. Then it works for me.
However if I have space on my disk.
But I do not work with "ionic serve", instead I use "npm run ionic: serve"